# Namespace scope vs scope inside class

Tags: c++, scope

There is this code:

```
namespace N {
   struct B {
      void f() {
         i;
         j;
      }
      int i;
   };
   int j;
}

int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

Variable `i` is found but variable `j` is not. How does it work that variable in the class can be used before it is declared but the same does not work for namespace? How `i` is found - compiler parses first all class to find all members then bind it with references from member functions?

Comment: j is a global variable weither there is a namespace or not.
A global variable must be defined before use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the bodies of member functions (as well as variable initializers) are processed in a later phase than the class definition.  You can check for yourself that the "declare before use" rule is still in full effect for class members, by trying to use members in other member declarations:

```
struct B
{
    char c[sizeof i];
    int i;
};
```

Demonstration: http://ideone.com/v1ksio

```
struct B2
{
    decltype(i) f();
    int i;
};
```

This also affects usage of the class itself which requires a complete type.

```
struct B
{
    static char c[sizeof (B)];
};
```

Demonstration: http://ideone.com/Z9XOzm

But this is ok, because variable initializers are processed when the construction definitions are, where all members are known and the type is complete:

```
struct B
{
    unsigned r{sizeof s};
    unsigned s{sizeof (B)};
};
```

Comment: This is a poor example.  The variable he is using is being used within a member function of the structure B, in which case, the declaration ordering of the member variable i is valid.

Comment: @ChrisCM: That's explained in the first sentence of the answer.  This is intentional contrast with the code in the question, to show that it's not members of classes that are special, but usage inside **bodies of member functions**.